# New Provisioning Profile Does not Appear in CodeSign DropBox

Tags: xcode4.5, testflight

I have been working on trying to get my app on test flight for THREE HOURS. Can someone PLEASE help? Here is what I have done:

1. Went to iOS Provisioning Portal, added a new device in the devices section
2. In portal went to provisioning section - under distribution tab, created a new profile 
   with a new name, made it ad Hoc and checked the box next to the new device that I added
3. submitted it, downloaded the certificate, opened the certificate in xcode
4. opened Xcode, looked in organizer window, I see the profile in provisioning profiles,
   says its valid
5. built the program
6. in xcode, went to the code sign identity section under build settings, hit the dropbox
   for debug and release, THE NEW PROFILE ISN'T LISTED!

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing? All the tutorials I read just gloss over this part and it seems the profile should be there but it isn't. Thanks!

Comment: oh my goodness, after all this time, suddenly I open xcode one last time and the new profile appears. what in the world!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding new profiles you have to do are fresh from within the organizer. It will solve the issue for future for you. I use different profiles and sometimes I have to use the refresh in organizer in order for excode to detect the new profile.

Hope this helps

Adrian